# Cannot add Spring dependencies with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I am new to Spring, and I am trying to create a simple Spring Boot "hello world" application, so I created a `build.gradle` file to add Spring Boot dependency:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE")
}
```

The problem is that it does not add the required jar(s), so I cannot use Spring annotations, such as `@Controller`.

What am I missing to make it work?

I am using IntelliJ Idea 2016.1, if this can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would help you :

http://start.spring.io/

just setup your dep and this include them all as a starter kit :)
Enjoy

Comment: Thank you, I will try it ASAP and let you know if it works :)

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks! However I can get no autocompletion on my IDE (and also all annotations/classes are marked as unknown classes). Is there a way to make it work too?

Comment: I solved it by adding `apply plugin: 'idea'`, and then running `gradle idea` (which generates all needed files/metadata, which allow you to use autocompletion)

Answer (score 0):

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
             mavenLocal()
             jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '1.3.3.RELEASE'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE because no repositories are defined`. Do you know how could I fix it?